# How to authenticate the http protocol url in android for azure web services?

Tags: android, authentication, azure-mobile-services, basic-authentication

I have an url with `http://`. So, i have to authenticate this with user credentials(username and password). I tried so many ways but i am not able to get the data. Everytime i got `401 error(unauthorized)`. How to access that `http://` url with authentication. Please help me.

My code is as follows

```
DefaultHttpClient Client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(
                "My-URL");
        httpGet.addHeader(
                "Authorization",
                "Basic "
                        + Base64.encodeToString(unp.getBytes(),
                        Base64.NO_CLOSE));
        httpGet.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");HttpResponse response = Client.execute(httpGet);

        System.out.println("response = " + response);
        BufferedReader breader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                response.getEntity().getContent()));
        StringBuilder responseString = new StringBuilder();
        String line = "";
        while ((line = breader.readLine()) != null) {
            responseString.append(line);
        }
        breader.close();
        result = responseString.toString();
        System.out.println("responseStr = " + result);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

i got 400 error(invalid host name). Could you please help me in this.

Comment: Which ways did you try? Did you follow the tutorials at https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-android-get-started-users/?

Comment: @ChrisAnderson-MSFT, i updated the query with my code. Could you please help me in this. Thanks

Comment: Why aren't you using the client Mobile Services provides? We don't support basic auth. You need to use OAuth against an IDP like Facebook or AAD.

Answer (score 1):

Azure Mobile Services does not support Basic authentication (unless you actually do the decode yourself). However, the error message suggests you are not getting that far.  Your URI should look something like https://your-website.azure-mobile.net.

Potential Solutions (either-or):

1. Switch to a supported authentication scheme - these are listed in the article that Chris Anderson referenced.
2. Write a website for Azure App Service Web Apps that does support basic authentication.  I'd recommend ExpressJS + Passport for this - here is a tutorial: http://blog.modulus.io/nodejs-and-express-basic-authentication

You don't seem to be using the Azure Mobile Services SDK, so this should cause no problems.  However, Basic authentication is relatively insecure, so I recommend looking at the alternate authentication mechanism that Chris suggests.